# Soap service invocation operation using google-apps script failing with 500 error code

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to invoke a GetWeather soap-service provided by WebserviceX  using Google App script and receiving the folllowing error on running the script:

```
Request failed for http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx returned code 500. Server response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'getWeather' expects parameter '@CountryName', which was not supplied. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at WebServicex.GlobalWeather.GetWeather(String CityName, String CountryName) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope> (line 12)
```

I have checked the parameters expected in the SOAP Request for GetWeather SOAP service but I unable to get as in which element in the soap request is causing the issue.
Below is script code for the same:

```
function testSoapSerivce() {
var wsdl2 = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL");
  Logger.log(wsdl2.getServiceNames());
  var weatherService=wsdl2.getService("GlobalWeather");
    var param2 = [ "GetWeather",
                { "xmlns" : "http://www.webservicex.net/" },
                [ "CityName", "New Delhi" ],
                [ "CountryName", "India"],  
              ];
  var envelope2 = weatherService.getSoapEnvelope("GetWeather", param2)
  Logger.log(envelope2);
  var result2 = weatherService.GetWeather(param2);
 Logger.log(result2.toXmlString());
}
```

GetWeather Service details can be found at the following link:

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=56

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet it looks like you added one comma to many.
Try it without the last one `"India"],];` The last one defines a empty index in the array.

I've taken a look at the webservicex site.
There actualy is a much easyer way to get the data. The site also offers a HTTP GET service

```
HTTP GET

The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

GET /globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=string&CountryName=string HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">string</string>
```

Why not use the UrlFetch service?

Comment: I removed the extra comma from the script but still I see the same error on running the script.Also,I can use the UrlFetch service but I wanted to try the SoapService provided for Google App Script.

Comment: At first i just had a look at your code. But looking at the errormessage you supplyed, i see: "expects parameter '@CountryName'"
Seems like the api is expecting a attribute node contrary to the documentation. You could try to fiddle with it by changing between creating attribute nodes and element nodes. i'm a litle stumped to with this.

Comment: I tried editing the param2 variable to the following:                                 var param3 = Xml.element("GetWeather", [
                Xml.attribute("xmlns", "http://www.webservicex.net/"),
                Xml.attribute("CityName", [
                  "New Delhi"
                ]),
                 Xml.attribute("CountryName", [
                  "India"
                ]) 
              ]);                                                    But still I am seeing the same error on running the script